# ValueError: The name "dense_1" is used 2 times in the model. All layer names should be unique

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to do Transfer Learning but I found with this error and I can't fix it.  Can anybody help me please?

```
import numpy as np
import os
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import load_model, Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import np_utils

Modelo = load_model('Mono64_9.h5')

x=Modelo.output
x=Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
preds=Dense(3,activation='softmax')(x)

model=Model(inputs=Modelo.input,outputs=preds)
```

> ValueError: The name "dense_1" is used 2 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.

Comment: If you're in a kernel/notebook, you may need to `K.clear_session()` when you re-run a model code-block. Otherwise, try naming your additional layers explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

What is most likely happening is that your loaded model already has Dense layers which are named using the generic defaults for the Dense layers when you construct them (i.e. `dense_1`, `dense_2`, etc.).  I'm unsure of what you're trying to do in your transfer learning task - whether you are adding more Dense layers to your network, or if you want to remove the Dense layers and add new ones.

Either way, to make this particular version of your code run, you'll need to add an additional `name` attribute to uniquely name the new layers.

Something like this could work:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import load_model, Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import np_utils

Modelo = load_model('Mono64_9.h5')

x=Modelo.output
x=Dense(512, activation='relu', name="dense_a")(x) # New
x=Dense(256, activation='relu', name="dense_b")(x) # New
x=Dense(128, activation='relu', name="dense_c")(x) # New
preds=Dense(3,activation='softmax', name="dense_output")(x) # New

model=Model(inputs=Modelo.input,outputs=preds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very likely that the model `Mono64_9.h5` has a layer called `dense_1`, just because that is the first auto-generated name for dense layers. You can explicitly give names to your new layers so they do not clash with the original model, like:

```
x=Dense(512, activation='relu', name='dense_10')(x)
x=Dense(256, activation='relu', name='dense_11')(x)
x=Dense(128, activation='relu', name='dense_12')(x)
preds=Dense(3,activation='softmax', name='dense_out')(x)
```

You can give layers any name, they are arbitrary and just for the user to refer to layers by name.